Confusion about negative clampinng voltage of unidirectional TVS diodes
I am currently looking at unidirectional TVS diode arrays to protect single-ended positive IO signals (TTL 3.3V, TTL 5V). From what I understand, unidirectional diodes start conducting above the Vrwm and clamp once the breakdown voltage is exceeded. For negative spikes, they would clamp to -Vf which should be around -0.7V.
However, looking at some unidirectional TVS diode array datasheets (https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PESD4USB5UTBS-Q.pdf), some seem to have an Ipp-Vcl curve that is quite symmetric. How is that different from bidirectional TVS diodes? Am I confusing the IPP-VCL curve with the diode curve?


In figure 5, the origins of both axes are near the bottom left. The TVS does not break down until 10.5 V, but then the voltage drop reduces to about 1.5 V and rises again with rising current.
In figure 6, the origins of both axes are near the top right. There is no breakdown; the TVS starts conducting near −1 V (actually at smaller voltages, but mA currents are not visible in this scale). There is something happening at −30 A, but that is way above the rated peak pulse current.

I see, so the clamping action is somewhat symmetrical, but the breakdown voltage is not
